# Embedding third-party framework in both app and my custom framework targets

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, frameworks

In my xCode project I have a Framework target, that I need to ship with other developers.
Also I have another app target that depends on Framework target.
Both my app target and framework target should use the same third-party framework. So I added this framework to both targets.
But when I run my app, I see a lot of warnings in console like this:

```
Class <ClassName> is implemented in both <Path to my framework> and <Path to my app>. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

I realized that warnings disappear when I remove -ObjC linker flag. But this flag is required by another frameworks that I use.

**So my questions is:**

How I can avoid such warnings?

Should I embed third-party framework inside my framework? (As I know this is not a good choise)

What I really want to implement: How can I build my framework so that other developers can download third-party framework independently so that my framework still can use it?

Comment: I assume this is a static framework that you are talking about?

Comment: @trojanfoe no, I'm talking about dynamic framework for iOS 8 and 9